# Setting More Than One Workspace

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, validation, workspace

I have a number of tables that contain known values in a field. For example, I have a soil type table with one field in it. That field contains a list of known soil types. I have another table that has a list of known vegetation types. I have various other tables that contain lists of other known types of other data.  What I want to do is:

- Read in each table, do a cursor search and add the values to a list
  via `tableList.append`
- Now that I have built each list, I want to compare the values from a
  separate feature class table to the known values in the list I have just created using `if row.SOIL_TYPE in SoiltableList:`
- In order to do this, I need to reset the workspace I guess, because
  you cannot set a path parameter for listing data in any of the arcpy
  Listing methods.

  ```
  env.workspace = r"C:\BASE_TABLES.gdb"

  SoiltableList = []
  VegtableList = []

  for table in arcpy.ListTables():   
     if table == "SOIL_TYPE":
        for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(table)
            SoiltableList.append(row.SOIL_TYPE)
     if table == "VEG_TYPE":
        for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(table)
            VegtableList.append(row.VEG_TYPE)

  # more iterations of table

  # Reset workspace
  env.workspace = r"C:\TEST_GDB.gdb"

  for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
     if fc == "SOIL_FEATURECLASS":
        for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc):
           if row.SOIL_TYPE in SoiltableList:
              print "YES"
           else:
              print "No"
    # More iterations of if/else logic to compare values from fields from various feature classes to the known values in the list I built.
  ```

The 2 questions I have are:

1. Do I need to reset the workspace the way I did above? is there a better way of doing this or is what I am doing completely acceptable?
2. Does my code make sense? Am I over complicating what I am trying to do? I though that maybe I would define a function or 2 to simplify the code, but I'm still in the process of figuring out what else I want the code to do.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Mike

Comment: Are your tables actually named `SOIL_TYPE` and `VEG_TYPE`? Those look more like field names than table names. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, both the table and the field in each table have the same name. I am writing some verification coding (i.e the feature classes are going to a client. I want to make sure the values in the feature classes are correct. I have people entering data into the feature class attribute tables by hand from some field surveys. I am writing some code to make sure the values that the data entry person entered is correct according to our known lists. I'll eventually be checking for capitalization, field length, etc)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using ListTables/ListFeatureClasses instead of just specifying the full path of the tables/feature classes directly?

Comment: Interesting. I was just questioning myself on that one. You're right. I can simplify the code by hard coding the argument without using the Lists. thanks :)

Comment: Do you really need ArcPy to meet the requirement in your first Comment?  Your data is in a File Geodatabase so if you converted your *_TYPE tables to domains then you would be able to use [**Validate**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m90000000v000000) on your data.

Comment: Thanks Polygeo. I didn't realize that functionality exists in ArcGIS. I read through the docs, but there are some things that I want to do, that I'm not sure this tool doesn't. I am going to post a new question about this and see if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much point in iterating over a list of tables if the number of them is small and you know exactly the names and locations of each one -- instead, just specify their paths in full:

e.g.:

```
soil_table = r"C:\BASE_TABLES.gdb\SOIL_TYPE"
veg_table = r"C:\BASE_TABLES.gdb\VEG_TYPE"
soil_fc = r"C:\TEST_GDB.gdb\SOIL_FEATURECLASS"
```

If the workspaces can change but the class names are static, you could join them with [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

e.g.:

```
table_workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fc_workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

soil_table = os.path.join(table_workspace, "SOIL_TYPE")
veg_table = os.path.join(table_workspace, "VEG_TYPE")
soil_fc = os.path.join(fc_workspace, "SOIL_FEATURECLASS")
```

That way you can avoid messing with the arcpy list methods and the `arcpy.env.workspace` property.

Comment: You could also put the tablenames into a list and then just iterate thru them, setting the path to each one using `os.path.join`.

Comment: Or, if you like one-liners: `soil_table, veg_table, soil_fc = map(os.path.join, (table_workspace, table_workspace, fc_workspace), ("SOIL_TYPE", "VEG_TYPE", "SOIL_FEATURECLASS"))`